# Override standard New Button Behaviour on Case with lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, case

I have 2 Ligtning apps which are accessed by almost same set of users.
The ask is to only display Record Types that are relevant to the application the users have logged into. For ex - If a user is logging into Sales App, only a subset of records are shown where as when they are logging from Finance apps they need to just see on the record type selections page only Finance specific record types.

Alternatively users are also ok with the fact that we can have 2 buttons, one for Sales, and Finance, however in that sort of design they would like to see only relevant record types on click on the button (finance vs sales).

Please advise how can we implement this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please take our [tour] and read [ask] - providing complete solution designs does not fall within our format. You can [edit] this question to add information and details.